# 3ds Max to three.js JSON exporter - materials not exporting at all

Tags: three.js

When I click on my model (imported to 3ds max from Revit), each element has a material (glass, steel, etc), but when i run the exporter, all 4 materials just show up like this:

```
"materials": [
{
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName"  : "dummy",
"colorDiffuse"  : [1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
"vertexColors" : false
},

{
"DbgIndex" : 1,
"DbgName"  : "dummy",
"colorDiffuse"  : [0.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],
"vertexColors" : false
},

{
"DbgIndex" : 2,
"DbgName"  : "dummy",
"colorDiffuse"  : [1.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000],
"vertexColors" : false
},

{
"DbgIndex" : 3,
"DbgName"  : "dummy",
"colorDiffuse"  : [1.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000],
"vertexColors" : false
}

]
```

Am I using the exporter wrong? Why aren't my materials being exported?!

Thank you!

Comment: What sort of materials are they in max?

Comment: Just plain ol' "Autodesk Material Library" materials. Like woods, concrete, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using procedural textures which can not simply be exported with the JSON exporter. You probably want to be using a standard material with a texture in the diffuse slot.

If you really want the procedural texture, you could "[render to texture](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-76F1E8AE-9E8F-40A7-A948-471D17E09DA9-htm.html)", then apply the resulting texture to the diffuse slot of a standard material. Which you could then export. You will also probably need to set up UVW coordinates.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the timely answer. It is super inconvenient though - the OBJLoader for three.js has problems.

Comment: How do I use a standard material?

Comment: Thanks, the trouble was I was using the Slate Material Editor instead of the easier one. It's working now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give to you is to export the model in an obj and mtl format and then upload both at clara.io.This website will allow you to convert those two files into a single json file.A python program also exists called convert_obj_three.py that can convert from obj into json format,but as far as I know,it won't convert the materials that you have assigned to your objects because it won't accept mtl files.

The link for this program can be found here:

https://github.com/timoxley/threejs/blob/master/utils/exporters/obj/convert_obj_three.py